# Cannot use some type in function call

Tags: go

Currently, I'm having two files in two packages.

## File `somepkg/something.go`

```
package somepkg

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Interfaces
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

type SomeThing interface {
  // some other methods
  Handle(handler *Handler)
}
type SomeThingImpl struct {
  handlers []Handler
}

type Handler interface {
  IncomingCall(request *IncomingRequest)
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SomeThingImpl implementation
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
func NewSomeThing() SomeThing {
  u := new(SomethingImpl)
  // some more operations with u
  return u
}
func (l *SomeThingImpl) Handle(handler *Handler) {
  fmt.Printf("handler: %s", handler)
}
```

## File `main.go`

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  )

type MyHandler struct {}
func (h *MyHandler) IncomingCall(request *somepkg.IncomingRequest) {
  fmt.Printf("Handler!")
}

func main() {
  mySomeThing := somepkg.NewSomeThing()


  handler := new(MyHandler)
  // works so far.
  mySomeThing.Handle(handler) // <-- here the compilation error occurs
}
```

trying to run `go build` yields the following compilation error:

```
{...}\main.go:20: cannot use handler (type *MyHandler) as type *somepkg.Handler in argument to mySomething.Handle:
    *somepkg.Handler is pointer to interface, not interface
```

whereas `main.go:20` refers to the line above where I'm calling `mySomeThing.Handle(handler)`.

Actually, both `MyHandler` and `somepkg.Handler` seem to be pointers. Both of them implement the same methods.

Why does the compiler not consider these types to be compatible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this method;

```
func (l *SomeThingImpl) Handle(handler *Handler) {
  fmt.Printf("handler: %s", handler)
}
```

Defined to take an interface pointer which is likely not what you want. What you're actually looking for is to have `*MyHandler` implement the `Handler` interface rather than `MyHandler` (or both could) so that you can pass your reference type into the method.

```
//new method sig
Handle(handler Handler)
// my preferred syntax for assignment here
handler := &MyHandler{}
// works just fine
mySomeThing.Handle(handler)
```

If you really want to keep the method sig how you have it, to make your code work you just need to do `mySomeThing.Handle(&handler)` but I'm doubtful that's actually what you want to do.

btw; In your code `*MyHandler` is already implementing the interface due to this method `func (h *MyHandler) IncomingCall(request *somepkg.IncomingRequest)` haveing `*MyHandler` as the receiving type as apposed to `func (h MyHandler)` which would make it so only `MyHandler` implements the `Handler` interface. Some little Go nuance with recievers and interfaces there.

Comment: But using the method signature `func (l *SomeThingImpl) Handle(handler Handler)`, doesn't do this produce a copy of `handler` when passing it by value?

Comment: @Atmocreations I'd prefer not to elaborate on how it technically works because I'd need to do some research but I'm pretty sure that is not the case. I'm pretty sure though that it's much like how a slice is actually a very small struct which points to the underlying array, the thing you pass in is a lightweight struct that has the type information. Not a value copy of the object itself.

Comment: @Atmocreations yep "An interface value is constructed of two words of data; one word is used to point to a method table for the value’s underlying type, and the other word is used to point to the actual data being held by that value." - so what you're passing is slightly larger thn a pointer, but not by much. You can read more about that here http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go

Comment: Okay then. What I want to avoid is to create expensive copies each time I pass my handler around. Well the handler is only a small object, but I'm currently learning golang and want to get used to it.

Comment: btw jordan orelli's article is a very useful one, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Never use a pointer to an interface (well, unless you know *exactly* why you would want to do so)

In order to pass that into the defined function, you would need to create the `*somepkg.Handler` explicitly (but don't really do this)

```
var handler somepkg.Handler = new(MyHandler)
mySomeThing.Handle(&handler)
```

If you define `Handle` as

```
Handle(handler Handler)
```

any type that satisfies the `somepkg.Handler` interface can be passed in directly.